# How to change carbon date type to string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

Edit: So I changed the title of my question. it was :Is built in timestamps for users migration different than other migrations we create in Laravel?

Ok here's the thing. Laravel out of the box had users migration. so I did not create any. and I needed an invoices table so I made a migration for that. Here are the two :

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

Invoices Migration :

```
class CreateInvoicesTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id')->unique();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->longText('url');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('invoices');
}
}
```

I put some initial data there. now when I vardump created_at for each of them I get different results!! I just tested like below and the results are :

```
foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        return var_dump($user->created_at);
    }
```

The result is :

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#185 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-11-08 14:50:29" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Tehran" }
```

But for the invoices :

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
    {
        return var_dump($invoice->created_at);

    }
```

I get this :

```
string(19) "2015-11-09 11:15:55"
```

now I don't really care why is that. How can I change the users timestamps created_at to be string. cause I have a function for date conversion that works perfectly on Invoices or any other data I got but for the users I get errors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look to your models, and see what differences there are there

Comment: @MarkBaker other than some fillable, protected and hidden variable definitions I don't see any other differences.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11

Comment: Looking to see if the `$timestamps` property is defined in either model is a good first check; likewise, look for any `$dateFormat` property

Comment: @sandeepsure well I have that downloaded, will check that right now.

Comment: @sandeepsure Okay I watched that, he does the opposite of what I wanna do. he converts a normal string type date to Carbon instance I wanna make the carbon instance to be a string :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite the Laravel Carbon objects, write the following function in your Model that you want to overwrite.

```
public function getDates() {
    return array();
}
```

This tells Laravel which dates you wish to return as Carbon objects (none) thus they'll all come out as DateStrings

Hope this helps - but do note, this will affect every date within the model. If you wish to have certain dates treated as Carbon object, add them into the array like

`array('created_at', 'updated_at')` etc

*Doc http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators*

Apologies, this above is for 4.2

In 5.1 you can just write an attribute `$dates` and give it a blank array

`protected $dates = []`

*docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators*

Comment: Thank you man. I'm on that. I added that but yet still it doesn't affect the new ones I create. but I think thats what I need. I added the `protected $dates = [ ]` to my User model but new users still have carbon instance date. but I'm sure that's a problem on my end.

Comment: Sometimes Models do get cached - I don't think it will work but worth a shot. Try doing a php artisan dump

Comment: Thank you again but nah it didn't I'm still getting carbon dates.

Comment: Ok sorry for bothering you again. I decided to make an accessor for my user model. it works perfectly. but the same does not work on my Invoice model any ideas?! :(

Comment: Hm I don't know. I know you can extend getAttribute() and use that to check if the property is a Carbon object, if it is you can return as a date string - I dont know if that will help though.